# Google maps APIs for Business returning error code 403 reason accessNotConfigured

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-geolocation

I am using Google Maps APIs for business to get location against Cell IDs and MAC addresses of WiFi access point.

That code was working fine on beta server. Now as I moved to production server, I am getting following response

{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "accessNotConfigured", "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project." } ], "code": 403, "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project." } }

In console, Beta server IP was added in allowed IPs. I have added production server IP as well. Still getting above response.

Do I need to generate new key after change in allowed IPs or any other change?

Answer (score 0):

The message is self-explaining *activate the API for your project*

Go to the console, select the desired project(when you have multiple projects), go to APIs & auth ->API's and activate the service **Google Maps Geolocation API**

Comment: **Google Maps Geolocation API** is active and its working fine on Beta server.